# ListView - вывести ID элемента в TextView самого элемента

Tags: android

Как сделать так, чтобы в одном TextView выводился номер элемента в массиве, а в другом - сам текст элемента? Не по нажатию, а при создании

Comment: Так а проблема то в чём? Если Вы можете вставить текст по позиции, то что Вам мешает вставить саму позицию?